While driving, the alarm beeps occasionally
While driving, the alarm beeps occasionally .diyatsu teros 1997

Do you mean the immobiliser/anti-theft alarm? I had a car where the seat belt buckle had a faulty switch contact, and would sometimes beep a warning. I fixed it by snipping the wire and twisting the ends together.

We recently had an EZPass transponder battery get too low and started beeping every 20-30 seconds or so ... that was annoying, too.
